# How to implement user registration in symfony project?

Tags: php, symfony, registration

I'm new in symfony and PHP and trying to make some simple project. I didn't have problems with simple requests or authentication but I can't understand how does registration work in symfony and how to implement it. As I understood - user send request to server with user data, we check it and put into database if data is correct. Otherwise return error. Am I right? If yes, then how to generate apiKey for user?  Can someone explain or just share a link or simple project?

Comment: What about reading the docs? You can start reading: [How to Implement a Simple Registration Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html).

Comment: Have you seen there anything about apiKey?

Comment: It's in the docs as well: [How to Authenticate Users with API Keys](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html), [How to Create a Custom Authentication System with Guard](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html) has an apiKey example aswell.

Comment: As I already said... What about reading the docs?

Comment: Did you read my question? I found only authentication with apiKey. But I need REGISTRATION with an apiKey

Answer (score 1):

add a property like `apikey`to your user class

when adding a new user, just generate some unique key,

here is a simple example, if you really want `unique` key you need further investigation on how to do that

```
$key = uniqid();
$user->setApikey($key);
```

now your api could require `apikey` as url-parameter something like:

```
 yourdomain.com/api/getItems?apikey=myuniqueapikey
```

in your `"apicontroller"` you could do some check like

```
$found = $em->getRepository('bundle:User')->findOneByApikey($request->get("apikey"));
if(!$found){
  throw new AccessDeniedException("ACCESS DENIED");
}else{
  // return things
}
```

so thats all very basic to get an idea

Comment: So, we just receive request with user data, check it, if it's OK, generate apiKey and add data to db?

Comment: dont know, thats up to you, in most cases i know at least an email adress needs to be certified

Comment: Yeah, check is email valid and other data. Everything other, that I told right? Or it works by some another way?